# how to write codes using vb.net to save information to PHP database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, vb.net, phpmyadmin

I am designing an interface using vb.net and the values inputted there should be saved in a database and I choose to design my database using mysql in phpmyadmin. I already made my database in php via localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php. But I do not know what commands / codes should I write in vb.net so that i.e. the value of textbox.text would be saved in database. Can anyone help me? Im only a beginner in visual studio as well as PHP and mysql. Thanks! Any help would be appreciated.:)

Comment: Google "vb.net mysql" - the database you are using isn't PHP (PHP is a language).  The phpMyAdmin scripts are designed for a MySQL database.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that your database isn't "written in PHP". But instead, it is MySQL. You will want to use MySQL's .Net Connector/Driver. (http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Comment: okay sorry so it is mysql database on phpmyadmin. can you help me how to get started? Im so confused. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone else has mentioned you are using the MySQL database not "PHP Database"

This tutorial should get you going.  I am linking right into part 3 as this is where they start to get into the code

http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-3

However I highly recommend that you start from Part 1 if you have no previous database experience.